# Find common elements between two list of list columns?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, lambda

Let's suppose this is the data frame I have:

```
dw = {'id' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'first_item' : [['Motherboard', 'Miscellaneous'],
                                        ['Miscellaneous', 'Mechanical Hardware'],
                                        ['Motherboard', 'Hard Drive'],
                                        ['Mechanical Hardware', 'Hard Drive'],
                                        ['Motherboard','Mechanical Hardware']],
      'second_item' : [['Motherboard', 'Hard Drive'],
                                        ['Mechanical Hardware', 'Mechanical Hardware'],
                                        ['Motherboard', 'Hard Drive'],
                                        ['Mechanical Hardware', 'Hard Drive'],
                                        ['Motherboard','Miscellaneous']]}
dw = pd.DataFrame(dw)
```

I want to find intersection/common elements between the first item & second item (row-wise), get an output like this:

```
   dw['new']
1 ['Motherboard']
2 ['Mechanical Hardware']
3 ['Motherboard', 'Hard Drive']
4 ['Mechanical Hardware', 'Hard Drive']
5 ['Motherboard']
```

i have tried below code, but it doesnt produce desired results:

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    return list(set(lst1) & set(lst2))

dw['new'] = dw.apply(lambda x: intersection(dw.first_item, dw.second_item), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Yes. That was a mistake (typo). Thanks for highlighting. But I am getting an error: unhashable type: 'list'.

Comment: yes. It worked now. I realized where the mistake was. Thank you very much. Could you help me with finding uncommon elements as well? i.e. eliminating the common/intersection elements & finding elements that are not shared in first & second item?

Comment: You are looking for symmetric difference. Try something like `list(set(lst1) ^ set(lst2))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `np.intesect1d`:

```
dw['new'] = [np.intersect1d(x,y) for x,y in zip(dw.first_item, dw.second_item)]
```

Comment: one more query: if I want to find uncommon elements (those elements that are not in first_item & second_item (uncommon elements), then what would be the code:

Comment: Use `np.setxor1d` instead of `np.intersect1d` to find set exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list1_as_set = set(list1)
intersection = list1_as_set.intersection(list2)             
intersection_as_list = list(intersection)
```

I'm not sure but try this !!

Comment: his question is for the two lists in each row in a pandas dataframe - this is just  for two sets.